# Nginx has ssl module, but thinks it doesn't

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm adding an SSL domain to a host. When I try to restart Nginx, it protests:

> Restarting nginx: [emerg]: the "ssl"
>   parameter requires ngx_http_ssl_module
>   in
>   /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my_site_conf:16

This is frustrating because I actually rebuilt Nginx and Passenger specifically in order to make `ngx_http_ssl_module` available; it wasn't in the running instance, so I took the opportunity to build with Nginx 0.8.53 and Passenger 3.0.1.

The relevant configuration block is

```
server {
        listen  0.0.0.0:443 default ssl;
        server_name  our-site.com;

        ssl_certificate  /etc/nginx/ssl/our-site.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/ssl/our-site.key;

        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
```

...etc. etc. (obviously I've obscured the host name, don't need this question coming up in searches for that domain.)

- How can I be sure the running Nginx instance has the SSL module active?
- Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Run nginx -V through SSH to verify it was built with SSL support. Also make sure it's been restarted and doesn't have multiple processes running.

Comment: Martin, your comment was the closest to the real solution; could you provide it as an answer?

Comment: this solved my issue too, SSL support isn't included by default. ["This module is not built by default, it should be enabled with the --with-http_ssl_module configuration parameter. "](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the real problem was that my init script (in `/etc/init.d/nginx`) was still calling the old version of Nginx, the one without the SSL module, because of a $PATH issue. Fixing some symlinks and deleting the old version fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the **SSL on** directive.

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule

Comment: it already enabled in "listen" directive

Comment: As noted [in the documentation](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSslModule), "Since Nginx version 0.7.14 the preferred way of enabling SSL is by using the `ssl` parameter of the `listen` directive"